# Store the order of something in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Let's say I have a table that's like the following:

```
name VARCHAR(50) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL
ordernum TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL
```

Also let's say I have 3 rows.

```
something     - 1
somethingelse - 2
somethingmore - 3
```

If i want to insert another entry called `something1`, and give it an ordernum of 2, how do I reorder all the rows that has an ordernum of 2 or greater? i.e. `somethingelse` becomes has an ordernum of 3, and `somethingmore` has an ordernum of 4?

I've heard the you can do it via `FIELD()`, but I'm unsure how to exactly.

If it's not possible, anywy to do it in PHP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your example:

```
UPDATE `table` SET `ordernum` = `ordernum` + 1 WHERE `ordernum` >= 2
INSERT INTO `table` (`name`, `ordernum`) VALUES ('something1', 2)
```

Comment: Would that be a multiquery in PHP then or can I still use prepare? Also that's a brilliant solution. Can't believe i missed that.

Comment: Glad this helps! You might just call mysql_query() twice in a row.  You could throw it in a transaction as well.